# Почему не удается найти позиционный параметр, принимающий аргумент?

Tags: powershell

Подскажите, почему командлет который выполняется на локальной машине

```
Get-TimeZone $hostname
```

При выполнении на удаленном хосте

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 192.168.1.10 -Credential Domain\UserName --FilePath "C:\Users\User\Documents\PS_script\TZ.ps1"
```

вызывает исключение

```
Invoke-Command : Не удается найти позиционный параметр, принимающий аргумент 
"C:\Users\User\Documents\PS_script\TZ.ps1".
строка:1 знак:1
```

Comment: _**Параметр FilePath указывает сценарий, расположенный на локальном компьютере**_. Диск C:\ точно указан латиницей? Каталог существует?

Comment: Да путь на латинице. Скрипт на локальной машине.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же ошибка была в скриптах на раздачу интернета и на отключение. Была ошибка синтаксиса, вместо netsh написал netch, еще добавил лишнего PC C:\Users\Администратор и > стрелочки тоже не надо было. У вас наверное тоже ошибка в этой части: "Invoke-Command -ComputerName 192.168.1.10 -Credential Domain\UserName --FilePath", связанная с синтаксисом

Answer (score 0):

двойной минус при указании параметра FilePath